# how to make a code break if max memory is reached

Tags: r

In RStudio, there are some occasions when the max memory is reached for some of my codes, e.g.

```
Warning messages:
1: In dlData$unique_id <- paste(dlData$institution_key,  ... :
  Reached total allocation of 16322Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In dlData$unique_id <- paste(dlData$institution_key,  ... :
  Reached total allocation of 16322Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "unique_id", value = c("100003|19920822",  ... :
  Reached total allocation of 16322Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "unique_id", value = c("100003|19920822",  ... :
  Reached total allocation of 16322Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Usually, in such case, the code still continues to run to the next step, but I am not sure if my code really ran fine. Is it possible to break the code if the max memory is reached, i.e any settings in R?

Comment: You could try using data.table. Since it avoids copies, you might be able to avoid the memory problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your code stop on *any* warning message by setting

```
options(warn=2)
```

If your code is otherwise clean enough (i.e., you never get any other warnings), then this should work fine. I don't know offhand of a way to catch just one specific warning.